# How to take values from multiple mysql rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to web development, just started php.

Situation and What I'm trying to do: so I have a uni project where a user has a dashboard and has all the events and each event detail listed under neath it. So on the dashboard I want something like this:

Event name

Event Start date

Event description

Event name

Event Start date

Event description

And repeat until all the rows in the database have been outputted.

I have tried to use this code:

```html
$eventsquery = ("SELECT * FROM Careerevents JOIN Tickets ON CareerEvents.Event_ID=Tickets.Event_ID JOIN Potential_Employee ON Tickets.User_ID=Potential_Employee.User_ID WHERE Email = '$email'");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $eventsquery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  
    
    for ($i=0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++) { 
    $eventname = $row['Event_Name'];
    $startdate = $row['Start_Date'];
    $enddate = $row['End_date'];
    $description = $row['Event_Description'];
    }
```

And after this I just echoed the results in the html part of the page of the dashboard. But only the first row shows up. How would I do it if i want all the row results to show up.

Comment: why a `for()` loop and not a `while()`, as every one else does?

Comment: you only fetch the first row here `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); ` once. Put that in a `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {..}`

Comment: because I'm inexperienced, just started php 5 days ago. Ok, @Jeff will try while

Comment: As a general point, if the variable in your loop definition (`$i`) isn't referenced inside the loop, it's a pretty big sign that you've gone wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only fetch once a single row with `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`.

You need to do that on a while loop like so:

```
$eventsquery = ("SELECT * FROM Careerevents JOIN Tickets ON CareerEvents.Event_ID=Tickets.Event_ID JOIN Potential_Employee ON Tickets.User_ID=Potential_Employee.User_ID WHERE Email = '$email'");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $eventsquery);

// EDIT after your comment 'showing only last row'
// I'd do the following
$events = []; // or $events = Array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $events[] = $row;  // copy the whole row to a new entry in events-array
    //$eventname = $row['Event_Name'];
    //$startdate = $row['Start_Date'];
    //$enddate = $row['End_date'];
    //$description = $row['Event_Description'];
}

// now you have all your events in an array called $events
// and can display them in another loop like so:

foreach($events as $event) {
     echo "Name: ".$event['Event_Name'];
}
```

Comment: Now its only showing the last row. Is my input in html wrong. I only echoed the variables, such as:
I feel like theres more to it

echo $eventname ;
    echo $startdate ;
    echo $enddate;
    echo $description;?>

Comment: I'm assuming theres more to the code in the output than just echo

Comment: you need to either echo them _inside_ the loop or save them to an array for lates access. (now we overwrite `$eventname` inside the loop everytime)

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

You're pulling the first row. So when you try to grab a value as

```
$eventname = $row['Event_Name'];
```

You're always pulling that same variable. You're never updating `$row` with a new value, so you're always getting the same one back. It's why people typically use a while loop, with the definition as the condition of the loop; as long as its valid (eg, it pulls a row), it'll continue the loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

That said, I recommend you learn PDO and not use mysqli. PDO is far more modern, more secure, and you'll run into it a lot more, and is functionally nearly the same as mysqli. If you're already comfortable with mysqli, its not a big jump over, but from a learning perspective, is FAR ahead.